How to auto generate Feign client in java\kotlin based on api interface?
I have that api interface for my next controller in spring boot
@RequestMapping("/v1/resource")
@Validated
interface ResourceApi {

    @Operation(summary = "get resource")
    @PostMapping("/get")
    fun getResource(
        @RequestBody request: GetRequest,
    ): PageableResult<GetResponse>

    @Operation(summary = "upsert resource")
    @PostMapping("/upsert")
    fun upsertResource(
        @RequestBody request: UpsertRequest,
    ): PageableResult<UpsertResponse>
}

I need auto generate somehow Feign client for that api like that
@FeignClient(
    contextId = "resourceClient",
    name = "service",
    path = "/v1/resource"
)
interface ResourceClient {

    @PostMapping("/get")
    fun getResource(
        @RequestBody request: GetRequest
    ): PageableResult<UpsertResponse>

    @PostMapping("/upsert")
    fun upsertResource(
        @RequestBody request: UpsertRequest
    ): PageableResult<UpsertResponse>
}

I am not interested on openapi generation like that guide or etc
Can OpenApi Generator generate interface feign clients?

So you have a solution but refuse to use it? Why?

@M.Deinum I do not want to garbage my project with open api yaml maintain

You can solve that maintain based on basic inheritance.
Also you must not describe @RequestMapping in api class due to error creating bean then feign client will be initialized
My code works nice with that:
@Validated
interface ResourceApi {

    @Operation(summary = "get resource")
    @PostMapping("/v1/resource/get")
    fun getResource(
        @RequestBody request: GetRequest,
    ): PageableResult<GetResponse>

    @Operation(summary = "upsert resource")
    @PostMapping("/v1/resource/upsert")
    fun upsertResource(
        @RequestBody request: UpsertRequest,
    ): PageableResult<UpsertResponse>
}

And Feign client
@FeignClient(
    contextId = "resourceClient",
    name = "service"
)
interface ResourceClient : ResourceApi

